# Bars inside highchart is overlapping when exported to PDF

Tags: highcharts, birt

[image]

I am using highchart and exporting that to PDF from BIRT tool so when exported the Bars inside graph is overlapping, actually in HTML the gap between bars is nearly an inch. can someone help me out in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Just need to add in plot options

```
series: {
            pointPadding: 0.1, //single bar
            groupPadding: 0,   //for group of bars
        }
```

Comment: You can add that as a theme for your charts as well.